# How to execute multiple "insert into values" Statement at once in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing statement

```
insert into [dbo].[Table_1] 
values ('43546354354', '35435454351', 'vvish', GETDATE(), 'vvish', GETDATE())
```

There are total of 154,155 lines.I tried and I go the following error.

> The script exceeds the Transact-SQL IntelliSense maximum script size setting. You can change the setting on the Text Editor/Transact-SQL/IntelliSense Page in the Tools/Options menu.

I also went to Tools=>Options=>TextEditor=>Transact-sql=>Intellisense and increase "Maximum script size to 5MB".

I tried moving the lines  of each 50,000 to different scripts but its taking very long time for me to move and execute. I have many other scripts with same size. Any suggestions please do help me.

Comment: It seems like, you were got the generated insert script from some other database and you are trying to insert data into your current db. So my suggestion would be if possible then try to insert the data using "Export Import wizard" rather than generating insert script.

Comment: Thank you. I did not generated insert script from other databsae. But I generated from Excel Spread Sheet. Now I going to fetch data into table using SSIS from Excel sheet. Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

With multiple connections. Period. Seriously, this is already a limitation of SQL Server (one connection can only operate ONE thing at a time - MARS is good, but you still can only send and execute one statement per line).

So, run a pool of lines, have X threads open a connection each and send line over line over line.

Alternatively split the files and execute them in parallel - same concept, except not on a line per line level.

Or just get real and use a code that parses them and uses SqlGBulkLoad. THe statements themselves should NEVER have been written like that, there are WAY More efficient ways to bulk load data then handling sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to improve performance by appending multiple tuples to a single `INSERT ... VALUES` statement:

```
insert into [dbo].[Table_1] 
  values ('43546354354', '35435454351', 'vvish', GETDATE(), 'vvish', GETDATE()),
         ('43546354355', '35435454352', 'vvisx', GETDATE(), 'vvisx', GETDATE())
```

But you will still run into maximum file *size* limits even if it has fewer *statements*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on some additional factors.
If your table has no triggers, indexes etc. you can do that load using "sqlcmd" command.
Just generate your script and put it in a file. Then you can run following script in Windows NT Shell:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -d MyDatabase -E -I -i MyScript.sql
```

However, as TomTom suggested, there are more beautiful/faster ways to do direct load from file rather than generating a script.

Answer (score 0):

You may build a stored procedure to handle the insert and have that stored procedure take a user defined table type as a parameter, this will allow you to pass your data in as a table to the stored procedure and the stored procedure can run as long as needed. I am making a dangerous assumption that you are taking data from some sort of file and developing these sql commands, so I would suggest using C# with dapper to pass create and pass the datatable to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are listing is related to IntelliSense, not your query.

IntelliSense is saying, "Hey, this thing is huge.  I'm not even going to try."

I suspect you've used Redgate or similar tool to generate your update script, found it was too large, then broke it into pieces.

What you need to do is make sure you have

USE [YourDataBaseName]
GO

at the top of each query.

Then when you execute you should get your results listed.